# Generate HTML with Rails and Jquery doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Im trying to make a button to add one form to create one Task with many Users, i put this:

```
$("#more").click(function(){
    i++;
    $("#more").after("<%= select_tag 'user_id_"+i+"',options_for_select(User.all.map { |u| [u.email,u.id] }) %>");

});
```

Right this appear normal but this genetare the tags Rails, appear this:

```
< %= select_tag 'user_id_4',options_for_select(User.all.map { |u| [u.email,u.id] }) %><%= select_tag 'user_id_3',options_for_select(User.all.map { |u| [u.email,u.id] }) %><%= select_tag 'user_id_2',options_for_select(User.all.map { |u| [u.email,u.id] }) %>
```

How can I make to appear this code in Rails?

UPDATE:

when i try put the code jquery in my .html.erb this dont execute, before was in application.js :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var i = 1;
    $("#more").click(function(){
        i++;
        $("#more").after("<%= select_tag 'user_id_"+i+"',options_for_select(User.all.map { |u| [u.email,u.id] }) %>");

    });


});


</script>
```

Comment: You need to run your code through a ruby interpreter. Try renaming your file to have a `.erb` extension.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try something, it's a wild guess but I hope it will answer your need. You can try this in a new application. Just create a **user** model, and seed some data, and add the gem 'jquery-rails' in your assets group. Run `bundle install` and restart your server.

In your **assets/javascripts/application.js**, ensure you have at least the following lines:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

In your **users_controller.rb**, define the **index** method to fetch all users from the database and render **index** template, it's very simple you just have to do like this:

```
def index
  @users = User.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

Then edit your view file in **views/users** and be sure it's named **index.html.erb**. This view will be displayed when you try to access localhost:3000/users with your browser (in details: it's a GET HTML request). Inside your view you'll write HTML and embed ruby, just the same way as you usually do. For now simply create a div and your give it the id "more" and you also place a link with attribute `remote`

```
<%= link_to 'click me', users_path, remote: true %>
```

Then create a new view file in **views/users** and name it **index.js.erb**. You notice that the extension changed, now we use *js.erb* instead of *html.erb*. In detail: when your page will do a javascript request (a GET JS in this case) to your **users#index** route, it will answer with the **index.js.erb** view. The big nice stuff here is you can write javascript code in this view that will get executed in your browser.

You remember we added `remote: true` to the link? This tells rails to general a link that will make a JS request. Magic.

So now you just have to write some javascript code in your **views/users/index.js.erb** file. Let's start with something super simple:

```
alert('Hello');
```

Go to your page (normally localhost:3000/users) and click the 'click me' link, you should see the javascript alert box displaying.

Let's do a second test, and integrate some ruby code. Change the content of your your **views/users/index.js.erb** by this :

```
alert('Ruby compute: <%= 1+1 %>');
```

And in your web page, you'll see the alert with the test 'Ruby compute: 2'. You just have to adapt this technique to your case in your application et voila.

The same technique (but with better explanation) can be found on this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery

Comment: Thanks by the help, the problem was in escape_javascript, if you can help me i thanks much dont know how works a dynamic form to add users, is so simple in theory: when i click in the buttom generate a form to add one user, one select, the buttom is 'more' i dont know how i make this, if some help me i thanks very very much is so complicated for me

Comment: See the videos at http://railscast.com you'll learn a lot. there is some info about form also. Don't forget to reward my answer, that's the rule here :)